# 2nd part of Java Script Function does not work

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I have a `validateFunction` on submit which checks to see if Name and Phone Number
are entered or not. (Phone is optional so it checks only if its filled)

The Name validation works perfect but the number does not.

I read on the forum something about any thing being called after first return will not be executed and I do not understand it.

Can some one help make this code work?

```
function validateForm()
        {
            var x=document.forms["enterGuest"]["guestName"].value;
            if (x==""||x==Null)
              {
                  alert("Guest Name Please");
                  return false;
              }


            var c=document.forms["enterGuest"]["guestNum"].value;
            if(c=="" || c==Null)

              {
              // Do nothing. Guest does not want to share the phone number.
                alert(" This Guest Cannot Receive A Call.");
                         return true;

              }
               else 
            {

                       c.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                       if (c.length !=10)
                        {
                         alert("10 Digits Please.");
                         return false;
                        }
                        else
                     {
                        var r = confirm(" Please Confirm The Phone Number Is Correct.");
                         if(r==true)
                         {
                         return true; 
                         }
                         else
                         {
                         return false;
                         }

                     }        
            }
```

Comment: There's also no reason to use the return statement anywhere in this code. Everything here is conditional and should get a chance to run if needs to.

Comment: Do you have a uppercase `N` in `Null`? It is supposed to be all lowercase.

Comment: What specifically about the number validation is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use if/else statements to avoid having to use too many returns in the javascript.

```
function validateForm() {
    var thisName = document.forms["enterGuest"]["guestName"].value
    if(thisName == "" || thisName === null) {
        alert("Guest Name Please")
    } else {
        var thisNum = document.forms["enterGuest"]["guestNum"].value
        if(thisNum == "" || thisNum === null) {
            alert("This Guest Cannot Receive A Call.")
        } else {
            thisNum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
            if(thisNum.length != 10) {
                alert("10 Digits Please.")
            } else {
                var checkThis = confirm("Please Confirm The Phone Number Is Correct.")
                if(checkThis == true) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Building on Nivas's fiddle, example here --> http://jsfiddle.net/XWLXn/1/

Answer (score 0):

The keyword **return** will cause the function to exit, so any code after a return will only run if the return is guarded by some form of conditional, (e.g. if (x)).

Its also difficult to know what's going on without your html, but I'll point out that your variable 'c' is being sett to the value of ["enterGuest"]["guestNum"]  and not a phone number (unless you accidentally copied it).  Also, use **null** not **Null** (not that its not capitalized).

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks well in your method, except that you have to have a lower case `N` in `null`: http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/XWLXn